# react typescript, structured array of object error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Why typescript give me warning on this line?

```
<TimeSlots hours={[{ dayIndex: 1, day: 'monday', }]}/>
```

how to I define type in jsx?

Comment: Show the warning message, and if possible, full code or an online demo which may help others to catch up with the problem you are facing quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't define the interface, or type alias for the props of `TimeSlots` component. This is how you can rectify the error.

First, you define an interface for the `TimeSlots` component:

```
interface Time {
  dayIndex: number;
  day: string;
}

interface TimeSlotsProps {
  hours: Time[];
}
```

And assuming you are using React Functional Components,

```
const TimeSlots: React.FC<TimeSlotsProps> = {

  // rest of the code
}
```